# Python inspect.ismethod retrurns False on an empty dict's methods

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of all methods on an object using `inspect`. I'm able to get a list of all members, but `instance.isfunction` and `inspect.ismethod` just return `False`.

```
x = [f for n, f in inspect.getmembers({}) if n == 'keys'][0]
x
#> <function keys>

inspect.isfunction(x)
#> False

inspect.ismethod(x)
#> False

x()
#> []
```

I'd expect at least one of those functions to return `True`, especially when I can *call* `x` like a bound method. This is Python 2.7.5.

Comment: From the [`ismethod` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html): "Return true if the object is a bound method **written in Python**.". You probably want `isbuiltin` or `isroutine`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isbuiltin).  Quoting from the docs:

> Return true if the object is a built-in function or a **bound built-in method**

(emphasis mine)

It also happens to be a [routine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isroutine) if that helps at all...

---

```
>>> import inspect
>>> x = [f for n, f in inspect.getmembers({}) if n == 'keys'][0]
>>> x
<built-in method keys of dict object at 0x7fd9c3027710>
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(x)
True
>>> inspect.isroutine(x)
True
```

Note that [`ismethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod) only includes methods which are written in python (which `dict.keys` certainly isn't -- At least not in CPython).

Comment: Apparently it's also a builtin for Jython.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann -- I would guess that it's a builtin for all implementations.